# Why are lights not working in my scene?

Tags: lighting

I have a scene with an object I modelled and UV-mapped.

When rendering, the object is very dark. The light in the scene doesn't seem to have any effect, either in rendered, shaded or solid mode.

Here's what I tried:

- adding sun, spot and other light types with no success.
- changing the light strengh to millions or other values
- moving the light all around
- adding a simple cube and it don't behave differently

I'm a beginner to the subject so I must be missing something very obvious.

Here is the scene in material preview:
[image: scene in material preview]

render:
[image: rendered object is very dark]

Any pointers ?

EDIT: don't why it was closed, the linked question doesn't help at all ?
EDIT2: closing and reopening the file solved the problem, no idea why it behave like this.

Comment: Hi, please add an [edit] as to what in the linked Q isn't helpful, is this in one scene, or others? Do no lights at all work for you? What is your world shading node setup? You may also add a sample file if it helps to illustrate the problem. [Pasteall](https://pasteall.org/blend/) or [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) are suitable for uploads.

Comment: `The light in the scene doesn't seem to have any effect, either in rendered, shaded or solid mode` . I read the linked question and as I understand it, it's only about the light problem in renders. Here the lights don't work in whatever mode I am. In other scenes, the light has effects in all modes.

Comment: Well, after closing and reopenning the file, light started to work again. I don't get it.

Comment: The black mirror ball in your screenshot may be an indicator of an issue with your OpenGL / graphics driver.

Comment: I just reproduced the issue, it seems to be happening after going back from sleep mode. Reopening the file solves it.